# Dialogflow: Programmatically set Fulfillment URL, Google Assistant Integration Settings

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am working on automating the deployment of my agent, but I'm having trouble doing some steps programmatically.

**Dialogflow Fulfillment URL**
I was able to get Export/Restore to work using the Dialogflow Enterprise API: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/export and https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/restore with the agentContent.
But, since the agentContent is an encoded string, there is no way to replace the Fulfillment URL before restoring. Is there a way to update the Fulfillment URL via API?

**Dialogflow Google Assistant Integration Settings**
Same question with the Google Assistant Integration Settings. Because this is part of the Dialogflow console, I see this as part of the agent. Ideally, we can programmatically create all parts of the agent. Is this available or on the roadmap?

**Google Actions: Action Discovery and Update**
Lastly, there is the Action Discovery and Update section of the Google Actions console, where we enable intents for push or daily updates. Is there a way to programmatically do this as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to update the fulfilment URL through the API.

Answer (score 0):

`agent_content` is indeed an encoded byte string of the zip file. But it's possible to programmatically generate the byte string after editing the contents of the export before zipping it.

Here's a python code snippet that may help:-

```
with open("skeleton_bot/agent.json", "r") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)

data['webhook']['url'] = "https://yoururl.com"

with open("skeleton_bot/agent.json", "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)

shutil.make_archive('skeleton_bot', 'zip', 'skeleton_bot')

with open("../config/skeleton_bot.zip", 'rb') as file_data:
    agent_content = file_data.read()
```

You can then use this byte string to import/restore to dialogflow